# What are these values on this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, board, monitor

As you can see from the images, this capacitor needs replacement, however I do not know what the top 2 values mean.
It doesn't state it's capacitance either...

I assume the first value is decijoule but I am not sure, the middle one just says 33, nothing else.

And the last one is 100 volts.

[image]

Also, if someone has any idea on how to replace this, I'd be very appreciated, as the capacitor doesn't seem to be soldered on the back of the board, it on some kind of plastic support, and it has 2 small soderings on the sides.
The board belongs to an LG monitor, an LG Flatron 22EA53VA to be precise.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a 33µF, 100V cap. The 32aJ marking denotes the type as specified in the factory. You have to consult the datasheet to find out what it means. It does **not** mean Joule.

Comment: I cant help you with values but the case is a typical SMT electrolityc cap

Comment: You simply desolder the leads . They are actually square-shaped wires which lead under the can horizontally, so desoldering can be a bit tricky. The support belongs to the part, you remove it along with the can.

Comment: Furthermore, it's a surface-mount capacitor. The tips of the leads that you see on the component side of the board are a very small part of what is soldered. To properly replace it, you need to be able to heat the board from both sides in an SMT rework station.

Comment: Do you mean SMD? @Jan Dorniak

Comment: SMT = Surface mounted technology. SMD = Surface mounted device. It's the same.

Comment: "As you can see from the images, this capacitor needs replacement" you can? what makes you think that?

Comment: It's swollen, you can see the "x" mark on top of it aswell.

Comment: Daniel that is a normal marking on those devices... https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=A8J2RXn8&id=7F00B4F6E4A93148CD8026E67EE0F7291A881642&thid=OIP.A8J2RXn8Hp2AdIqJhN6srAEsEs&q=smt+capacitor&simid=608035584204866615&selectedIndex=187&ajaxhist=0 It's part of the manufacturing process

Comment: Not on these capacitors. Because these are layered with a plastic cap, you can't see the marking because it is underneath. If you look on the first image, there is a similar capacitor without the marking. Furthermore, the markings are inwards, not outwards like this capacitor. Which leads me to believe it's swollen

Comment: Daniel it depends on the cap, some are printed right on the metal, others have a shrink wrap film on them. that's the seam lines you are seeing.

Comment: The inductor beneath it looks like it has been cooking though

Comment: Well, I'll take your word for it. I don't know much about hardware. But I'll replace it anyways, it's cheap and easy.

Comment: google **smt electrolytic capacitor** then click on images. You will see both kinds ( and a lot of other crap) Good luck with the repair though/

Answer (score 1):

Considering the physical size and voltage rating i suggest this is a 33uF capacitor. You can desololder it by using a solder tweezer or by hot air (make sure to shield adjacent components with aluminum foul or similar) or by desoldering one leg slightly lift it up and then desolder the second leg. Make sure you find a capacitor model with apropriate physical size and consider the polarity because it is anelectrolytic cap.

Something like https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/de/nichicon/PCR2A330MCL1GS/493-13793-2-ND/4694783

Comment: thanks, i'll pay a visit to the local hardware shop next monday and see if they have similar caps

Comment: @Daniel, local hardware shops don't usually have this kind of capacitors. You should shop on-line for SMD components. But why do you think these electrolytic caps are faulty? Your images show no bulging of signs of leaks.

Comment: Well, maybe not, but the top of the capacitor has a bulge. And the monitor problem is when I turn it on, it turns off immediatly after, I have to wait around 15 mins for it to "warm up" so it mantains turned on. Which is usually a capacitor problem. Not sure if the local hardware shop has these, but I'll give it a shot, they have almost anything I could think off.

Comment: I just came upon this topic as I also have the same problem but with an LG 22EA63V monitor which is behaving the same after a shorted graphics card turned the monitor completely white and a high pitched "zzzzzzttt" was heard for a second or two.

Did the OP @Daniel mange to fix his monitor by replacing the capacitor mentioned in the original post?